# Closing wxpython panel with Seaborn plot embedded

Tags: python, wxpython, seaborn

I have a seaborn plot embbeded in a wxPython panel, like this:

[image]

This is the code I made to accomplish this:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import wx

class SimplePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="pastel", color_codes=True)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        self.planets = sns.load_dataset("planets")

        self.years = np.arange(2010, 2014)
        sns.factorplot(x="year", ax= self.ax,data=self.planets, kind="count",palette="BuPu", size=6, aspect=1.5, order=self.years)
        sns.despine(left=True)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    fr = wx.Frame(None, title='test', size=(800,600))
    panel = SimplePanel(fr)
    fr.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**Problem**: it works fine, except when I close the window the program doesn't terminate. I think it has to do with the seaborn plot because I've run the program without it and it closes normally. But I don't know how to fix it. I've tried also to had a close functionality to the window (below `self.Fit()` line) like this:

```
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseWindow)

    def OnCloseWindow(self,event):
        self.Destroy()
```

But it doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `plt.close()`?

Comment: Yes @Phlya I tried that as well, it doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

Erase the seaborn plot object before destroying the window.